# Can you link up twice in one turn in Age of Steam?

Tags: age-of-steam

During the Move Goods phase you have the option to either:

- Move a good
- Increase your Engine Links

Then each other player goes and you then get a second chance to move a good.  Can you choose the **Increase Engine Link** option for both goods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the game, and dug out the rules to clarify.

Under section 5, *Move Goods*, it states the following:

> In ONE of the two opportunities to Move Goods, the player may instead
>   opt to move their disk on the Engine Track up one link. The maximum
>   number of links is still 6 links.

Therefore, you may not use the Increase Engine Link option twice, and move no goods.

Answer (score 2):

I've played Steam rather than Age of Steam, but I think it's similar?  In any case, I found this clarification on [an online Age of Steam FAQ](http://members.fortunecity.co.uk/hopalong/faqaos.htm):

> Q4. As mentioned in the section titled "Moving Goods", a player may
>   forego shipment during a round in order to "increment" his engine link
>   level. It does not specify in the rules by how many links a player may
>   increment his engine, only that the maximum is 6 links. Can a player
>   increment his links by more than one per round? In other words, can I
>   go straight from a 2 link engine directly to a 6 link?
>
> A4. You can only move your engine level up by 1 for foregoing 1 cube
>   shipment. You are only allowed to do this once per goods movement
>   phase. Note that the word "increment" means "To increase the amount of
>   ONE unit". Also be aware that if you get the Engineer you can still
>   forego a shipment in order to get a maximum upgrade of +2 on the turn
>   as a whole.

I can't vouch for the accuracy of this ruling, but it *does* tally with what I seem to remember from playing Steam, that you couldn't just increase your Engine madly early on, it was a slow, gradual process.  So I'd say once per goods movement phase sounds like a pretty safe bet.